# jxbrowser WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

I am a new JxBrowser user who is experimenting with replacing the UI in a portion of an existing Swing application with modern web-based UI technology.  I am able to get a basic "Hello World" message display in a window within this application.  All looks fine, except that I notice this message on the console:

```
Nov 14, 2017 4:24:34 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
-- Product name: JxBrowser
-- Licensed version: 6.x
-- Licensed to: 
-- License type: Evaluation
-- Generation date: Nov 14, 2017
-- Expiration date: Dec 14, 2017
-- License info: Single-user license
-- Current date: Nov 14, 2017
JxBrowser license valid.
```

I am asking about the first 2 lines, and specifically whether they indicate some sort of problem with JxBrowser, or whether I can ignore them.

I searched the web for this problem, and found this, which I bet is related: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139507

I am on Windows 7 64-bit.  "java -version" says the following.  This is a 32-bit version of Java.

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore this warning. Such warnings are usually reproducible when UAC does not allow Java to access this registry node, but JxBrowser will work properly even without having access to it.